# requestFocus() en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un `formulario` en `Java` con 7 campos a rellenar.

- Nombre
- Apellidos
- DNI
- Telefono
- Direccion
- Ciudad
- Email

El orden será: nombre > apellidos > dni > telefono > direccion > ciudad > email

**¿Cómo podría hacer para que otorgara el foco (requestFocus()), el primer campo que haya vacío?**

**Código:**

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //Atributos generales para el cliente.
    String nombre = textfield_nombre.getText();
    String apellidos = textfield_apellidos.getText();
    String DNI = textfield_DNI.getText();
    String telefono = textfield_telefono.getText();
    String direccion = textfield_direccion.getText();
    String ciudad = textfield_ciudad.getText();
    String email = textfield_email.getText();

    //Comprobamos que están todos los datos insertados...
    if(validateForm()) {
        //Comprobamos si el DNI no existe en la base de datos...
        if (!Conexiones.cargar_dni().contains(textfield_DNI.getText())) {
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
            //Llamamos al método alta_cliente() para insertar el cliente en la base de datos.
            Conexiones.alta_cliente(cliente);
            dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Este DNI ya EXISTE en la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_DNI.requestFocus();
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!!!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        textfield_nombre.requestFocus();
        textfield_nombre.setBackground(Color.decode("0xB4FF48"));
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas usando un layout?

Comment: @x-rw He utilizado Java Swing, sin probar el código de layouts, simplemente arrastando los elementos al JFrame. Igual es menos pro... ¿o qué me recomiendas?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes perfectamente validar dinamicamente los campos que tengas sin repetir y repetir instrucciones similares; resulta mas practico si se tienen esos `JTextField` "separados" en un único contenedor del resto de componentes de la *GUI* para solo iterar en lo que interesa, los campos de texto.

Para este caso suponiendo que todos los componentes están en un mismo `JPanel`, una buena aproximación seria tener un método que realice la validación (*recorriendo la lista de componentes*) y retorne un simple estado lógico `true` para cuando se tengan todos campos rellenos o `false` para cuando al menos uno esté vacío.

```
private boolean validateForm() {
  for(int i=0;i<contentPane.getComponentCount();i++) {
    JComponent c=(JComponent)contentPane.getComponent(i);
    if(c instanceof JTextField) {
      if(((JTextField)c).getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        ((JTextField)c).requestFocus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Teniendo lista la validación, quiero detenerme en un detalle no menor:

Si a uno o mas de tus `JTextField` le pasas por ejemplo uno o mas espacios en blanco pues se los va a considerar como caracteres, se van a contar y `getText().isEmpty()` "fallaría" porque en realidad no estaría vacío, la razón del ser del método `trim()` es que quite espacios al comienzo y final del `String` para garantizar que verdaderamente no hay datos en el campo.

Finalmente el metodo `button_OKActionPerformed` que haga la implementación de todo:

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  //...
  if(validateForm()) {
    //Realizo mis consultas a la base de datos...
  } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!!!", 
                             "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Comment: La función la entendí, lo implementé en el button pero no me funciona. Si hay campos vacíos me va al que está ocupado. Edito el código.

Comment: Tal vez sea por la manera en que NetBeans acomoda los componentes, hablas preguntado por algo al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344717/cambiar-de-jtextfield-mediante-tab-netbeans  Utiliza un *Layout* distinto al que usa el IDE, para la prueba que hice usé un `FlowLayout` y funcionó 100%

Comment: No entiendo porqué con TAB se desplaza entre los jTextField de la forma que indico en el enunciado de mi duda, pero.. ¿por qué al comprobar si está vacío o no tiene el protocolo de "quién está mas cerca"?

Comment: Seria bueno saber que *layout* usaste en aquel problema, de hecho no pude reproducir ese comportamiento, a priori si también le cambias la disposicion de los componentes por el *layout* por defecto de un `JPanel` que es el flow lo arreglas, acá el fuente completo del `requestFocus()` https://pastebin.com/2EvkPk8d

Comment: No entiendo de layouts, únicamente hago la interfaz con Java Swing arrastrando los elementos al contenedor. Entonces entiendo que no haya forma de ir campo a campo vacío con el orden que yo quiero, sin depender del layout...